# How to check if an element exists in the HTML using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, selenium-webdriver

I have a question. I find an element on the pages using the class, and display the text from there, and then `split()` it disassembles, but there is an error when there is no element, it does not parse.

Code:

```
spans =  driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='ipsContained ipsType_break']")

for span in spans:
    atag = span.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a")
    print(atag.get_attribute('href'))
    urlik = atag.get_attribute('href')
    driver.get(url=urlik)
    time.sleep(2)
    urla = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ipsPagination_pageJump").text
    for page_number in range(int(urla.split()[3])):
        page_number = page_number + 1
        driver.get(url=urlik + f"page/{page_number}")
        time.sleep(2)
        imgs = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "cGalleryPatchwork_image")
        for i in imgs:
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", i)
            time.sleep(0.2)
            print(i.get_attribute("src"))
```

I need check this:

```
urla = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ipsPagination_pageJump").text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To attempt to find an element on the pages using the class and display the text from there irrespective of the element being present or not you can wrap up the code in a [try-except{}](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70407389/7429447) block handling the [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995294/7429447) as follows:

```
driver.get(url=urlik)
time.sleep(2)
try:
    urla = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ipsPagination_pageJump").text
    for page_number in range(int(urla.split()[3])):
        page_number = page_number + 1
        driver.get(url=urlik + f"page/{page_number}")
        time.sleep(2)
        imgs = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "cGalleryPatchwork_image")
        for i in imgs:
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", i)
            time.sleep(0.2)
            print(i.get_attribute("src"))
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Element is not present")
```

Comment: I need to check if there is an element, if not then just continue the code

Comment: @Deprool That's the logic here. If _`driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ipsPagination_pageJump").text`_ returns `urla` then only you `split()` and do the other stuff. Else we are handling the _NoSuchElementException_ and moving to the next **`span`**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```py
urla = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ipsPagination_pageJump")
```

Use

```py
urla = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "ipsPagination_pageJump")
if urla:
    urla[0].text
```

`find_elements` method returns a **list** of web elements matching the passed locator.
So, in case such element(s) existing `urla` will be a non-empty list while non-empty list is interpreted in Python as a Boolean `True`.
In case no matching elements found `urla` will be an empty list while empty list is interpreted in Python as a Boolean `False`.