# Python selenium the problem with is_displayed()

Tags: python, selenium

The purpose is I want to check the button is exist on web page and then click it, if not exist, just skip.
But, it's not works if not 'is_displayed()', please suggest me how can I modify the code, thanks!

Here is the code:

```
button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ra_on"]')))
if button.is_displayed() == True:
    button.click()     #means turn to ON. It's works.

else:
    print('It's ON ready.')    #means turn ON ready. It's not works.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find_elements` that will return a list of `Web element`, if found at least one `Web element`, if it does not find anything the `list` will be empty.

**Code:**

```
try:
    if len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='ra_on']")) > 0:
        print("element must be displayed, do whatever you wanna do here")
        button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='ra_on']")))
        button.click() 
    else:
        print("Element with xpath //*[@id='ra_on'] not found.")
except:
    print("Just skip it")
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the button if it is clickable or else just to skip you can wrap up the line within a [`try-except{}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70407389/7429447) block and you can use the following solution:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ra_on"]'))).click()
except TimeoutException:
    pass
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```