# How to check if the element is present in Sel-python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to automate a page wherein the page can sometimes lead to a custom error page like the below snapshot. The scenario is the page doesn't encounter an error often but when it happens I want to display a message.

[image]

The code that I tried is as follows:

```
login_actions.enter_username(self.username)
login_actions.enter_password(self.password)
login_actions.login()
error_mesg = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="//h2[@class='exception-http']")
if error_mesg:
    print("encountered an error")
else:
    #continue with the actions
```

With the above code, the web driver tries to find the element first which doesn't appear often and the test case fails.
Can anyone suggest a solution to find the presence of elements?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium: Check for the presence of element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50610553/selenium-check-for-the-presence-of-element)

Comment: It didn't work for me :( But thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle the probable ***custom error page*** you can wrapup the validation within a [`try-except{}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70407389/7429447) block and catching the *`NoSuchElementException`* you can use the following solution:

```
login_actions.enter_username(self.username)
login_actions.enter_password(self.password)
login_actions.login()
try:
    driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//h2[@class='exception-http']")
    print("encountered an error")
    # steps to leave the error page to continue with the other actions
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
# steps to continue with the other actions
```

Comment: If the element ```find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//h2[@class='exception-http']")``` is not found, where do I add the further actions? In the except part?

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Yes, that worked! Appreciate it

Comment: Glad to be able to help you.