# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException when click and no button exists

Tags: python, selenium, exception

I have a problem to make the function continue without the error NoSuchElementException.In this case the function is Selenium and it clicks on one point on the page to select all the files and the other to download the files, however sometimes the search has no files to click or no items to download, and it gives an error of NoSuchElementException. How do I pass it and continue the function without stopping the function? However the function stop with the error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
sleep(2)
select_all = driver.find_element(
By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ng-form:ng-detail-dataTable:ng-data-table:selectionMode"]/div/div[2]')
select_all.click()
sleep(5)
download_all = driver.find_element(
By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ng-form:ng-toolbar:dowloadXmlAction"]')
download_all.click()
sleep(2)
```

Comment: 1) Is the `select_all` element remains clickable when the search has no files? 2) Possibly the `download_all` element is disabled/absent when the search has no files. Can you please confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use `find_elements` instead of `find_element`, because it always returns a list, so if it doesn't find anything returns an empty list, while `find_element` raise error if it doesn't find the element.

```
select_all = driver.find_elements(
By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ng-form:ng-detail-dataTable:ng-data-table:selectionMode"]/div/div[2]')
if select_all:
    select_all[0].click()
    sleep(5)
    download_all = driver.find_element(
    By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ng-form:ng-toolbar:dowloadXmlAction"]')
    download_all.click()
    sleep(2)
```

where `if select_all:` means "if `select_all` is not empty"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a try-except block and perform the click there

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


select_all = driver.find_element(
By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ng-form:ng-detail-dataTable:ng-data-table:selectionMode"]/div/div[2]')
try:
    select_all.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    print('Element was not present')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the *`select_all`* element is always clickable/selectable irrespective of any files(s) is/are present or not and the *`download_all`* element remains invisible/disables when there is/are no file available to be downloaded you can wrap the click on *`download_all`* within a [`try`-`except`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70407389/7429447) block catching [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995294/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

select_all = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ng-form:ng-detail-dataTable:ng-data-table:selectionMode"]/div/div[2]')
select_all.click()
sleep(5)
try:
    download_all = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ng-form:ng-toolbar:dowloadXmlAction"]')
    download_all.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
sleep(2)
```